# Can the 68-95-99.7 rule be used to test normality?

Tags: normal-distribution, goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption

Suppose I have a data which has 90% values in $\pm 1 \sigma$ range, 98.8% values in $\pm 2 \sigma$ range and 99.9% values in the $\pm 3 \sigma$ range. Can I refute that this data is distributed normally?

I have around 7000 observations (edited in from comments)

Is it okay from a normality perspective to have more than "prescribed" percentage of observations in these ranges?

Comment: how many samples do you have total?  Can you give breakdowns by sample counts as well as percentage of population?

Answer (score 4):

> Suppose I have a data which has 90% values in +-1 sigma range, 98.8% values in +-2 sigma range and 99.9% values in the +-3 sigma range. Can I refute that this data is distributed normally?

How unusual that would be with data that was actually drawn from a normal distribution depends on sample size. However, we can infer that you would have a sample size of no less than 1000 (otherwise you couldn't get 99.9% unless that percentage is rounded to 3 figures (in which case 99.949999% would round down to 99.9, and 99.85000001 would round up to 99.9, implying the sample size is at least 667).

[It turns out that from OP comments, the sample sizes in question are about 7000]

> Is it okay from a normality perspective to have more than "prescribed" percentage of observations in these range ?

You should be able to turn any of those comparisons of sample and population proportions into an asymptotic test (though if you have access to the original data a more typical goodness of fit test would be a better choice from a couple of perpectives).

For example, with that large a sample size, getting 90% of values within 1 standard deviation of the the mean would not happen with data actually from a normal distribution.

More formally, imagine that you have a sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution and you estimate its mean and standard deviation. Then it would seem that the proportion of observations inside $({\bar{X}}-k{s},{\bar{X}}+k{s}$) should be asymptotically normal with mean $\pi=2\Phi(k)-1$ and variance $\pi(1-\pi)/n$ (where Phi is the standard normal cdf). However, the fitting of the sample mean and standard deviation used in the standardization reduces the variance substantially.

(this is related to the impact of parameter estimation on the chi-square, where here the chi-square would be based on the proportion inside vs outside 1 standard deviation from the mean)

Once the sample size is large, the effect on the variance is not much impacted by sample size (nor terribly much by changing $k$, though somewhat more so); the standard deviation of the sample proportion for $n=7000$ and $k$ near $1$ is approximately $\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{\pi(1-\pi)/n}$ for $c$ around $1.476$. The normal approximation is adequate and works well enough for any sample size in this region (it seems to work okay for $n$ well below 1000 for example, or $n$ above 10000).

Here's a normal Q-Q plot of the distribution (using 100,000 simulated samples each of size 7000) of the standardized proportion within 1 sd of the mean, for a normally distributed population.

[image]

The red line is the line through the origin with slope 1; the fit is quite good.

So this simple test works as follows:

Compute $p_1$, the proportion within 1 standard deviation of the mean. It has expected value $\pi=0.6827$ and it has standard deviation $\sigma$ of about $\frac{1}{1.476}\sqrt{\pi(1-\pi)/n}$.

Then $Z=\frac{p_1-\pi}{\sigma}$ is very close to standard normal.

Collecting specified constants, we could write $Z=\sqrt{n}\cdot\frac{p_1-0.6827}{0.3153}$.

So for example, if $p_1=0.70$ with $n=7000$ then $Z=4.59$. (I presume you know how to find the p-value for a two-tailed Z test.

In your case you're reporting $p_1$ on the order of $0.9$. This results in $Z$ values in the region of $57.6$ or thereabouts. This is so huge as to be pointless to calculate a p-value for (if we treat it as actually normal that's around $5\times 10^{-723}$... no actual use to have so exactly but there it is. Of course it's still actually discrete - akin to a binomial but affected by the standardizing - however, calculating a more accurate p-value to any decent accuracy will be tedious and pointless at the same time in this case - we could proceed by simulation, for example, but we would never get far enough into the tail to get anything but a very weak upper bound on the p-value -- we might be able to show it's smaller than $10^{-7}$ say).

The thing is, t this sample size, very likely all your tests will reject with very low p-values (making it pointless to compute in the first place), but if you just need a p-value because someone *insists* on having one anyway, something simple like this should be enough to satisfy them that indeed the p-value is extremely tiny (as was obvious as soon as we saw the first percentage anyway).

---

Alternatively you could look at a chi-square test but the extreme inequality in probability for the intervals (within 1 sd, inside 2 but not within 1, etc)  has some undesirable properties, and then combined with the effect of parameter estimation (which is based on the full sample, leaving us with a result that's no longer chi-square) will make that slightly more involved.

The chi square statistic is simple enough. Let's take your figures as exact (after rounding to whole counts):

> 90% values in +-1 sigma range, 98.8% values in +-2 sigma range and 99.9% values in the +-3 sigma range.

and your "n=7000" from the comment under my answer.

Then we have:

```
   Bin      Observed   Expected   (O-E)²/E
 |Z| ≤ 1     6300       4778.8     484.2 
 1<|Z|≤2      616       1902.7     870.1 
 2<|Z|≤3       77        299.6     165.4  
 3 < |Z|        7         18.9       7.5

 Total       7000         7000    1527.2
```

So we have a chi-square statistic of 1527.2 but the test statistic doesn't have a chi-square distribution because of the parameter estimation from the full-sample.

We could work it out if we simulate normal samples of the same sample size, standardize them by their sample statistics, and calculate a chi-square statistic for each, obtaining the distribution of the statistic under the null at that sample size (it wouldn't be very sensitive to the sample size so
such a simulation should be adequate for other large sample sizes). In this case the statistic is so extreme simulation won't get anywhere near that far into the tail. We could at best give an upper bound on the p-value that way.

However, we do have a shortcut - when the chi-square distribution is sufficiently accurate, the distribution should be bounded between a $\chi^2_3$ and a $\chi^2_1$ so that should suffice to get upper and lower bounds on the p-value, though out this far into the tail the chi-square approximation would surely be questionable.

This would bound the p-value between  $4.8 \times 10^{-334}$ and $7.4 \times 10^{-331}$. A pointless calculation in this case, perhaps, but it's there for completeness.

Comment: I have a data of around 7000 observations, is there any formal tests to strengthen our hypothesis of non normality of such data ?

Comment: It seems that part of your answer is missing (last sentence)

Comment: I thought that quantile was defined using interpolation if it does not fall exactly on a point.  The median of 4 equally spaced elements is the midpoint between the central two elements, right?

Comment: @Tim No wonder that was confusing -- that was a misplaced quote from the question, which the immediately prior paragraph was a response to. I've moved it up where it should be and turned it into a quotation.

Comment: @EngrStudent I'm not sure what you're saying here. Well I understand your words but I can't see what you're saying about my answer, Can you clarify?

Comment: @SahilTalwar Yes, that's the intent of my last paragraph (the p-value would be so tiny as to make it pointless to calculate). I'll add some details.

Comment: @Glen_b - i really missed the sample count.  I thought that a 99th percentile of 50 elements was at linear interpolation between the last 2 elements.  I was hoping you would say something (kung-fu master) like "because of <insert cool name here> the linear interpolation is not valid, so the 99.9th percentile only leads to more than 1000 samples".  Sorry.

Comment: @Sahil I have described a test of normality based on the proportion within 1 s.d. of the mean where the mean and standard deviation are computed from the sample itself.

Comment: For the given example, as you note it's obvious the data are non-normal unless the sample is small.  But more generally, wouldn't a modified $\chi^2$ test based on the given bins be natural--and more powerful than a single Binomial test?

Comment: @whuber generally not much more power, for a circumstance like this if n is small ... and power is hardly the problem here with n=7000. The chi-square's power is best with proportions nearly equal. With such different p's the chi-square can have a surprising amount of bias for small deviations from the hypothesized distribution (smaller than we have of course, so it wouldn't be a big issue for this example), There's also the issue that we have to account for the parameter estimation which we can't simply subtract degrees of freedom for so there'd be a simulation required for that too. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... Finally, if we're really worried about power we should consider the possibility of other tests, like (say) a discrete version of an Anderson-Darling perhaps. I figured showing how to take the simplest comparison and make a test would be more instructive. But you're right that I should at least discuss the chi-square more. I had written another sentence or so of explanation there at the end where I discuss why I didn't do the chi-square but it got cut off somehow; I should show how to calculate the p-value in this situation, or at least give the bounds that come from chi-squared tables.

Comment: I was thinking of the general situation, not just the large-$n$ one.  I like the A-D test idea: it could readily be adapted to such data and would likely be one of the most powerful approaches possible.